# Display one label pr group in an igraph network

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
    id_1 id_2    id_3_all
1   1aju 1uts 50:1aju_ARG
2   1am0 6e8s 22:1am0_AMP
3   1byj 1pbr  9:1byj_GE1
4   1byj 2esi  9:1byj_GE1
5   1byj 2et8  9:1byj_GE1
6   1byj 2f4u  9:1byj_GE1
7   1byj 2o3x  9:1byj_GE1
8   1byj 5bxk  9:1byj_GE1
9   1byj 5zej  9:1byj_GE1
10  1byj 1f27  9:1byj_GE1
11  1byj 1o9m  9:1byj_GE1
12  1byj 2f4s  9:1byj_GE1
13  1byj 2f4t  9:1byj_GE1
14  1byj 4f8v  9:1byj_GE1
15  1byj 5z1i  9:1byj_GE1
16  1eht 1o15 47:1eht_TEP
17  1f1t 1q8n 45:1f1t_ROS
18  1f27 2f4t  9:1byj_GE1
19  1fmn 6c63 13:1fmn_FMN
20  1fmn 6c64 13:1fmn_FMN
```

Where id_1 and id_2 are network connections/vertices and column 3 is a group label. I would like to make a network graph where the group label is shown.
After converting the df to an igraph object, and plotting it:

```
g4 <- graph_from_data_frame(RNA_families,  directed =  F)

E(g4)$group <- as.character(RNA_families$id_3_all)

plot(g4,
     edge.label = E(g4)$group,
     edge.label.cex = 0.7,
     edge.label.dist = 1,
     vertex.label = NA,
     alpha = 0.1,
     vertex.size = 1
)
```

I get a plot akin to this:

[image: Plot with labels]

As you can see the labels are very cluttered and the plot is very hard to read. What I would like to do is to display only one label pr group. Is there any way this is feasible?

Comment: As a work around, can you set all the group labels besides the first occurrence of each to "" (i.e. blank) in your data frame?

Comment: After posting this I thought of the same solution, @JordanHackett . But I am not entirely how to write this, as I am failry new to R

Comment: If your data frame is called "df" you should be able to do something like df$id_3_all[duplicated(df$id_3_all)] <- ""

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks :D

Comment: @JordanHackett  Could you write this up as an answer?

Comment: Sure no worries done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around, you set all the group labels besides the first occurrence of each to "" (i.e. blank) in your data frame. This can be accomplished like so:
If your data frame is called `df` you can do `df$id_3_all[duplicated(df$id_3_all)] <- ""` to set all duplicate names to blank.